# Using xml:space="preserve" in POI SXSSF

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

When using POI's `XSSFWorkbook`, cells (via `sharedStrings.xml` inside the resulting xlsx file) are automatically preserving whitespace, i.e., entries in `sharedStrings.xml` look like

`<t xml:space="preserve">   </t>`

After switching to `SXSSFWorkbook`, however, this is no longer the case.

Is there any way to get this `t` element programmatically and add `xml:space="preserve"` to it using POI's existing API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may be using an old version of Apache POI.  According to the [Apache POI change log](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html), this bug (#52972) was resolved in version 3.9.

> 52972 - preserve leading / trailing spaces in SXSSF (poi-developers)

Please upgrade your POI libraries to 3.9 and see if that resolves the issue.